# How to make cut in cylindrical shape without braking up roundness?

Tags: modeling

I'm recently start learning blender and i have a trouble with crating cuts in cylinder with subsurf modifier without breaking up roundness. Anyone have a idea how to model this kind of piece(picture 1)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Either start with more edges, to have them evenly spaced around the whole cylinder, or correct the circular shape later.